# Government Spending, Econimic Growth Correlation

Tags: macroeconomics

A major problem when testing hypothesis in economics is the lack of historical data. Is there research into the correlation between long term economic growth and government spending, that is based on a broad set of historical data?

The question of government contribution to economic growth is central to economics, so the relationship should be tested with as much as reliable data as possible. For example western countries were already compiling population, GDP and inflation data in the early 19th century. At the end of the 19th century any modern nation had the needed statistics. Even for periods before that GDP could be estimated and taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: A difficult question. Correlation is positive with the _level_ of economic output (GDP PC). As for the rate of change of GDP PC, it's debatable, and the data before 1950 won't help much.

Comment: Why data before 1950 is not helpful?

Comment: You overestimate the quality of historical economic data. GDP is very hard to calculate and if you realize that even data series as 'trivial' as debt are full of breaks (see for example the historical debt database of the IMF) you'll understand that using old data is quite tricky.